# MS Access Pie Chart

Tags: sql, ms-access, charts, ms-access-2016

I have to make a pie chart from a request in a MS Access report.

Here is how the data I have looks like :

[image: Data]

I basically want a pie chart showing the proportion of each, but it doesn't work and looks like this (with the configuration I have done, but I tested checking all the boxes one by one and it doesn't change) :

[image: wrong pie chart]

[image: configuration]

I also tried to make a query giving this results :

[image: data 2]

And the result is quite the same (a bit better however)

[image: wrong pie chart 2]

I think the solution would be to make a request taking my results and placing them in two rows but only one column but I don't know how I could do this. If anyone can help me building this request or finding the solution to tell Access my data are in a row and not in a column, I'd be grateful !

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You *accept* an answer. You don't edit the title of your question.

Comment: Yes I know this, but I have to wait for two days to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was basic.

I dimply did this :

```
SELECT [Connexion en cours] + [Connectés] As Connexions
FROM
(
   /*REQUEST 2*/
);
```